# How to implement in RXswift and RXCocoa of UITableView Inside of tableview cell?

Tags: rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I'm new to RXswift and currently working in a project that requires rxswift with UITableView inside of UITableViewCell

Below are some of the codes I've done so far, but every time scroll up/down, it doesn't show the right value

```
    var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    viewModel.listExperience.asObservable().bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: cellExperienceTableViewCell.getCellId(), cellType: ExperienceTableViewCell.self)){
            row , data, cell in

             cell.lblTitle.text = data.title ?? ""
             cell.lblDate.text = data.startDate ?? ""
             cell.lblDetails.text = data.body ?? ""

            let filtered = self.viewModel.getDataCommentInRow(row) /* returns Variable<[Comments]> */
             cell.setCommentTableView(row: row, filtered: filtered)
             cell.tableViewOffset = self.storedOffsets[row] ?? 0
             cell.tableViewComments.reloadData()

           }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

here's the code of the tableView inside of my tableView cell

```
  func setCommentTableView(row : Int, filtered  : Variable<[ExperienceComment]>){

    tableViewComments.tag = row
    filtered.asObservable().bind(to: tableViewComments.rx.items(cellIdentifier: commentCell.getCellId(), cellType: CommentCell.self)){  indexPath , data, cell in
        cell.lblComment.text = data.body
      }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Anyone knows how to achieve this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the only thing you have to do is add a `prepareForReuse` method in your table view cell. In it add `disposeBag = DisposeBag()`. Make sure your DisposeBag is a var inside the cell in order to do this.

If I'm right, the problem is that when the cell is getting reused, it starts reading from multiple `filtered` observables because they all get bound to the same tableViewComments.

Comment: Thanks,I forgot to add here the declarations of disposeBag, but I declared a disposeBag outside as of that method(one inside of my TableViewCell and one inside of my viewController).

"If I'm right, the problem is that when the cell is getting reused, it starts reading from multiple filtered observables because they all get bound to the same tableViewComments."
Yeah, that exactly what happened to my tableviewCell. I'll check that 'prepareForResue', Thanks Daniel

Comment: Right, so replacing your disposeBag in the `prepareForReuse` causes the current bind(s) it's holding to end and prepares the cell for the new bind.
Remember, the way to shut down an Observable pipe is to either have the producer complete/error or have the consumer dispose the connection.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I added the I added the disposeBag inside of prepareForReuse in tableView cell and everything is ok now. :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. Keep in mind you aren't "adding" a dispose bag in prepareForReuse. Rather you are *replacing* the dispose bag (thereby deleting the old one and disposing of everything in it.) That's why this works.